# Genug über mich oder genug von mir?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

> But enough about me, how have you been?

How to translate "enough about me" in the above context?

> genug über mich

or

> genug von mir

?

Comment: For the close voters, I consider this question **on-topic**. It's precise, short and potentially useful to others.  "Translation requests to German should be of general interest and should provide sufficient context."

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, that both proposal are bordering to a word-by-word translation, which don't equally well work in German.

I consider as typical translation:

> Jetzt habe ich aber genug von mir erzählt, wie geht es Dir?

Without that additional context *genug von mir* could also mean, that it is now time to pass over to a different speaker, so *genug über mich* seems a better approach. The first match in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=abhQUMVHKxAC&pg=PT127&dq=%22genug%20%C3%BCber%20mich%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje4bnX3NDlAhUE8BQKHfD9AiEQ6AEIbDAJ) seems to support this.

Comment: As German native speaker, the phrase "Soweit zu mir,..." can also be used.

Comment: As a side note, "genug von mir" might come across more negatively than intended. It might be understood as a shorter form of "Du hast genug von mir", "You're fed up with me". So it might get a vibe of "enough about me already".